# Bluetooth Packets Get Lost While Doing Some Other Calculations

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm, spp, packet-loss

I have my Android device and WT-12 bluetooth module communicating over RFCOMM. My data rate is about ~180kbps roughly. I don't have any problem in my data if I only get the data and don't process it online. However, when I try to use a counter to d some calculations with the data, it is possible I lost data. I think it is happening since the buffer is written before I read it. Is there a way to avoid this?
    My code to capture data over bluetooth is as following:

```
void beginListenForData() {
    stopWorker = false;
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while ((!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)) {
                try {
                    try {
                        bytesAvailable = myInputStream.available();
                        capturedSampleNumTwice += bytesAvailable;
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        Log.e("null pointer","null pointer");
                    }

                    if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                        myInputStream.read(packetBytes, packetBytesAddress, bytesAvailable);
                        if(recordingActive){
                            packetBytesAddress += bytesAvailable;
                            Log.i("packetBytesAddress", String.valueOf(packetBytesAddress));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    workerThread.start();
}
```